# Make an activation link non-expirable

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a question about Activate a New Account by Email.

I follow this [Registration – Activate a New Account by Email](https://www.baeldung.com/registration-verify-user-by-email)

My question is about

> It will expire within 24 hours following its creation

```
@Entity
public class VerificationToken {
    private static final int EXPIRATION = 60 * 24;
[...]
```

I wanted to know if we could make sure that the link has no expiration time or if it is not in good security practices and why?

Comment: This question might be better suited for the security stachexchange site. For example check this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40512/how-long-should-an-e-mail-address-confirmation-link-last-and-why-must-it-expire/40517#40517)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by making this modifications should work.

1. Remove properties and methods on 2.1 that will no longer be needed:

```
@Entity
public class VerificationToken {
    //private static final int EXPIRATION = 60 * 24;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String token;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    //private Date expiryDate;

    //private Date calculateExpiryDate(int expiryTimeInMinutes) {
        //Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        //cal.setTime(new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime()));
        //cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, expiryTimeInMinutes);
        //return new Date(cal.getTime().getTime());
    //}

    // standard constructors, getters and setters
}
```

2. Remove the commented if statement on example 3.1.1 (so that the system will not verify if it is expired):

```
@Autowired
private IUserService service;

@RequestMapping(value = "/regitrationConfirm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String confirmRegistration
  (WebRequest request, Model model, @RequestParam("token") String token) {

    Locale locale = request.getLocale();

    VerificationToken verificationToken = service.getVerificationToken(token);
    if (verificationToken == null) {
        String message = messages.getMessage("auth.message.invalidToken", null, locale);
        model.addAttribute("message", message);
        return "redirect:/badUser.html?lang=" + locale.getLanguage();
    }

    User user = verificationToken.getUser();
    //Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   // if ((verificationToken.getExpiryDate().getTime() - cal.getTime().getTime()) <= 0) {
     //   String messageValue = messages.getMessage("auth.message.expired", null, locale)
       // model.addAttribute("message", messageValue);
       // return "redirect:/badUser.html?lang=" + locale.getLanguage();
    //} 

    user.setEnabled(true); 
    service.saveRegisteredUser(user); 
    return "redirect:/login.html?lang=" + request.getLocale().getLanguage(); 
}
```

Despite it's perfectly doable, it's not recommended due to security reasons. As user [second](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11514534/second) said, in [Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) you will obtain an appropriate response about the security behind email confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable expiration you may want to check this part of their code:

```
    User user = verificationToken.getUser();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    if ((verificationToken.getExpiryDate().getTime() - cal.getTime().getTime()) <= 0) {
        String messageValue = messages.getMessage("auth.message.expired", null, locale)
        model.addAttribute("message", messageValue);
        return "redirect:/badUser.html?lang=" + locale.getLanguage();
    }
```

Just delete `if` statement that checks expiration token and redirects to `badUser.html`

For some cases links without expiration can cause security flaws. For example:

You have a link that resets user password (always valid link).

Someone stole this link from you somehow.

Now this guy can change password for your account any time. Only one option for you is to create new account.